# How to make Eclipse support JQuery

Tags: jquery, eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to integrate Jquery with Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043198/is-it-possible-to-integrate-jquery-with-eclipse)

Found WTP does not support jQuery by default. Any other plugin exists supporting jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Aptana](http://www.aptana.com/), it can be installed as a plugin in Eclipse. Take a look [here](http://docs.aptana.com/docs/index.php/Getting_started_with_Aptana_and_jQuery) for jquery support

Answer (score 6):

You can add jquery to any html project you open in eclipse by adding this line to your html

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

You can also integrate jquery with autocompletion to your Eclipse installation with jQueryWTP.

http://www.langtags.com/jquerywtp/

http://javascriptly.com/2008/10/jquery-eclipse-wtp/

Answer (score 0):

This plugin has just been released a few days ago :

http://www.langtags.com/jquerywtp/