# any tool/plugin to work with Jquery

Tags: jquery, eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to integrate Jquery with Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043198/is-it-possible-to-integrate-jquery-with-eclipse)

I need code completion feature for JQuery under Eclipse. I am wondering any plugin/tool can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Aptana pugin](http://docs.aptana.com/docs/index.php/Plugging_Aptana_into_an_existing_Eclipse_configuration) and turn on the [JavaScript Code Assist Feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351847/aptana-plugin-for-eclipse-and-jquery-code-assist/1352017#1352017) .

Answer (score 0):

Try [Aptana](http://www.aptana.com/)

Look at these SO posts as well:

- [Aptana Plugin for Eclipse and jQuery code assist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351847/aptana-plugin-for-eclipse-and-jquery-code-assist)
- [Is it possible to integrate Jquery with Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043198/is-it-possible-to-integrate-jquery-with-eclipse)